# no uni code support in TTSearchlightLabel

Tags: iphone, animation, text, three20

the `TTSearchlightLabel` class in the [Three20](http://three20.info) framework ignores whitespaces and latin letters. Its render code looks like this :

```
CGContextSelectFont(context, [_font.fontName UTF8String], _font.pointSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1, -1));
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, _textColor.CGColor);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, x, y, [self.text UTF8String], self.text.length);
```

I am not very familiar with this low level rendering but did somebody get rid of this ?  I tried also `kCGEncodingFontSpecific` but its getting worst even.

I guess the issue is not really fixable so quickly, is there an alternative to have this kind of text effects ?

Thanks a lot,
Guenter

Comment: i have also the same problem. does anybody have fixed this issue already?

Comment: Have you searched their site or help/forums? I assume someone else would run into this problem and post about it there first. You should file a bug report if no one else has.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17040) for `CGContextSelectFont`’s encoding parameter says:

> `textEncoding`
>   A `CGTextEncoding` value that specifies the encoding used for the font. For a description of the available values, see “[CGTextEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH3g-C016181)”.

The possible values are:

> `kCGEncodingFontSpecific`
>   The built-in encoding of the font.

and

> `kCGEncodingMacRoman`
>   The MacRoman encoding. MacRoman is an ASCII variant originally created for use in the Mac OS, in which characters 127 and lower are ASCII, and characters 128 and higher are non-English characters and symbols.

Change the parameter to kCGEncodingFontSpecific and it should display correctly.